# HTTP Get Request "Moved Permanently" using HttpLib

Tags: python, http, httplib

**Scope:**

I am currently trying to write a Web **scraper** for [this specific page](https://420101.com/strain-database). I have a [pretty strong](https://github.com/MarcelloLins/GooglePlayAppsCrawler) "Web Crawling" background using C#, but this `httplib` is beating me off.

**Problem:**

When trying to make a `Http Get` request for the page specified above I get a "Moved Permanently", that points to the very same URL. I can make a request using the `requests` lib, but I want to make it work using `httplib` so I can understand what I am doing wrong.

**Code Sample:**

I am completely new to Python, so any wrong `language guideline` or syntax is C#'s fault.

```
import httplib

# Wrapper for a "HTTP GET" Request
class HttpClient(object):
    def HttpGet(self, url, host):
        connection = httplib.HTTPConnection(host)
        connection.request('GET', url)
        return connection.getresponse().read()

 
# Using "HttpClient" class
httpclient = httpClient()

# This is the full URL I need to make a get request for : https://420101.com/strain-database
 
httpResponseText = httpclient.HttpGet('www.420101.com','/strain-database')
print httpResponseText
```

I really want to make it work using the `httplib` library, instead of `requests` or any other fancy one because I feel like I am missing something really small here.

Comment: It's better to include the code in the question. Especially as it is only short.

Comment: Isn't there a typo? HttpClient or httpClient?

Comment: Probably the higher level library is automatically following the redirect. You probably have to do that manually in httplib.

Comment: @Malvolio if it's for educational purposes then using httplib is just fine.

Comment: The redirect occurs from `www.420101.com` to `420101.com` (no www). If you can leave that off in your initial request you have no issue. Is that an acceptable outcome?

Comment: @PaulRooney -- "educational purposes"?  My understanding is that `httplib` does not automatically handle redirects, and `requests` does.

Comment: @Malvolio exactly, so if Marcello wanted to learn about redirects, he could use `httplib` and get his 'hands dirty', but when it came time to do something for production it's `requests` all the way.

Comment: Also note you use the params to HttpClient backwards. You pass (host, url) but the function takes (url, host). As you've discovered already its https and needs a httplib.HTTPSConnection instance.

Answer (score 2):

The problem i've had too little or too much caffeine in my system.

To get a https, I needed the HTTPSConnection class.

Also, there is no 'www' in the address I wanted to GET. So, it shouldn't be included in the host.

Both of the wrong addresses redirect me to the correct one, with the 301 error code. If I were using requests or a more full featured module, it would have automatically followed the redirect.

My Validation:

```
c = httplib.HTTPSConnection('420101.com')
c.request("GET", "/strain-database")
r = c.getresponse()
print r.status, r.reason

200 OK
```

Comment: Looks like you ripped the example form the same place as me:)